# Measure retention on specific page using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have a browser games portal and would like to measure retention for specific games via Google Analytics.

So, basically, the question we want to answer with data is this one:
Of the people who play game X, what % returns to game X within 7 days.

In our case, a game play is a pageview (or an impression with the game name in a custom dimension).

Analytics has `User Retention`, but as I understand this, it's only on a sitewide level by default.

We tried making custom segments for specific games, but the problem is that we want to access this data programmatically.

Is there a way to achieve our goal via `User Retention` (`ga:cohortRetentionRate`) or should we look for a proxy metric?

Comment: This would be much easier to solve if you had them login with google/facebook/anything before allowing them to play.

Comment: @Patrick completely agree but mandatory registration is something not possible in our sector (barrier to start playing must be as low as possible). Once we have our optional login system (working on it), we could use that, but the data will be slightly skewed so ideally we would still find a way to display the data even for the logged out users.

Comment: Maybe we can drop a cookie, and send a custom analytics event when they return.

Answer (score 2):

To set this up you'll need two additions to your code:

1. Set a Cookie value for the game they're playing. Maybe just steal the path. Attach the event to game activation.
2. Custom event if this cookie is already set and matches the game they're playing.

The code would look like this (after GA container initiation):

```
var gameID = window.location.pathname; // Example uses a path grab
if (!!$.cookie(gameID)) {
ga('send', {
hitType: 'event',
eventCategory: 'Games',
eventAction: 'replay',
eventLabel: gameID
});
} else {
$.cookie(gameID, 1, {expires: 7}); // Cookie expires after 7 days.
ga('send', {
hitType: 'event',
eventCategory: 'Games',
eventAction: 'first play',
eventLabel: gameID
});
}
```

Anything can be used for the gameID and custom events can be shortened to:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Games', 'first play', gameID);
```

You can then pull reports based on general first plays, and compare it to replays. This cookie doesn't unset so you'll get multiple hits from the same user on the custom event. If you don't want this, check the cookie value with the 'if' statement and set it on the replay event. So no value=set cookie, 1=replay event, 2=do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do that in analytics. But what you can do is create a new tracking code and site, and put that tracking code on only the page with the game. That will tell you how many returning users there to that page alone.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a solution that would work programmatically either.  If they have 100 games, they would need 100 tracking codes and they would have to go into each GA account to check on the specific game.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael but Stephen's comment is spot on in our case: it doesn't scale as much as we need it to.